# Setting up Google Voice/Hangouts to use my phone number

Tags: google-voice

I have an iPhone 4S with Verizon as my carrier. I'd like to be able to use Google Voice and Google Hangouts to call people and have it show up on their caller ID as my phone number. Is there a way to set this up without having to pay money and switch my carrier over?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. On a computer go to [Google Voice](http://voice.google.com), go to the ["My Number"](https://www.google.com/voice?pli=1#phones) page, and select "change/port", and finally, select use my mobile number. Google Voice will guide you thru the rest of the process.